filament fileupload insert to media table issue
im stuck at uploading file using filament, hope someone can help on how to save it to media table
below is my filament form, view part is working
public function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\RichEditor::make('comment')
                ->hiddenLabel()
                ->placeholder(__('Type your reply here...'))
                ->disableToolbarButtons([
                    'codeBlock',
                    'undo',
                    'redo',
                    'attachFiles',
                    'h2',
                    'h3',
                    'blockquote',
                ])
                ->required(),
            Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('files')
                ->multiple()
                ->disk('s3')
                ->visibility('private')
                // ->collection('comment')
                ->acceptedFileTypes(['application/pdf', 'image/*'])
                ->maxSize(5120)
                ->openable()
                ->hiddenLabel(),
        ])
        ->statePath('data');
}

after click submit will trigger function below
$data = $this->form->getState();
$helpdesk_comment['helpdesk_id'] = $this->record->id;
$helpdesk_comment['user_id'] = auth()->id();
$helpdesk_comment['comment'] = $data['comment'];
$helpdeskComment = HelpdeskComment::create($helpdesk_comment);
foreach ($data['files'] as $field_name => $value) {
    $helpdeskComment->addMedia($value)->toMediaCollection('comment');
}

all data can insert, but i dun know how to insert the uploaded media
below is result of dd($this->form->getState())
array:2 [▼ // app/Filament/Resources/HelpdeskResource/Pages/ReadHelpdesk.php:92
  "comment" => "<p>test test</p>"
  "files" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "01J5B4VA59HCBSHVFSVXKAQWEA.jpeg"
  ]
]

how can i complete the

$helpdeskComment->addMedia($value)->toMediaCollection('comment');

i only get file name from $data

You can just use Spatie Media Library Extension
here's the link for extension :
Spatie Media Library Extension

this will automatically save files to media table for you, just follow the instruction correctly.

